# Using Mathematica to Automatically Reveal Matrix Structure

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica

I spend a lot of time looking at larger matrices (10x10, 20x20, etc) which usually have some structure, but it is difficult to quickly determine the structure of them as they get larger.  Ideally, I'd like to have Mathematica automatically generate some representation of a matrix that will highlight its structure. For instance,

```
(A = {{1, 2 + 3 I}, {2 - 3 I, 4}}) // StructureForm
```

would give

```
{{a, b}, {Conjugate[b], c}}
```

or even

```
{{a, b + c I}, {b - c I, d}}
```

is acceptable.  A somewhat naive implementation

```
StructureForm[M_?MatrixQ] := 
  MatrixForm @ Module[
    {pos, chars},
    pos = Reap[
           Map[Sow[Position[M, #1], #1] &, M, {2}], _, 
           Union[Flatten[#2, 1]] &
          ][[2]];  (* establishes equality relationship *)
    chars = CharacterRange["a", "z"][[;; Length @ pos ]];
    SparseArray[Flatten[Thread /@ Thread[pos -> chars] ], Dimensions[M]]
  ]
```

works only for real numeric matrices, e.g.

```
StructureForm @ {{1, 2}, {2, 3}} == {{a, b}, {b, c}}
```

Obviously, I need to define what relationships I think may exist (equality, negation, conjugate, negative conjugate, etc.), but I'm not sure how to establish that these relationships exist, at least in a clean manner. And, once I have the relationships, the next question is how to determine which is the simplest, in some sense?  Any thoughts?

One possibility that comes to mind is for each pair of elements generate a triple relating their positions, like `{{1,2}, Conjugate, {2,1}}` for `A`, above, then it becomes amenable to graph algorithms.

**Edit**: Incidentally, my inspiration is from the Matrix Algorithms series ([1](http://www.ec-securehost.com/SIAM/ot60.html), [2](http://www.ec-securehost.com/SIAM/OT77.html)) by Stewart.

Comment: Might be hard in general. For structure checking e.g. is it Hermitian with symbolic variables assumed real, could use as a utility something like SameQ[mat,ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Transpose[mat]]]]. If you work with explicit Re and Im then built in HermitianMatrixQ may also be of some use. Likewise SymmetricMatrixQ.

Comment: @Daniel, I knew it wasn't easy, but I thought I'd ask. Both `HermitianMatrixQ` and `SymmetricMatrixQ` are nice, and would be useful in displaying matrices with only those types of symmetry. Unfortunately, as is often the case, the matrices I work with usually have more complicated symmetries, in addition to be Hermitian, and I'd like a tool that can display such structure. Definitely not a simple request.

Comment: @Daniel, also, `MatrixPlot` and `ArrayPlot` are sometimes useful, but they don't reveal the structure of symbolic matrices, and it is difficult to use them to determine hermiticity. Ideally, I'd like to perform one test to more clearly reveal the structure, and the current tools require multiple tests.

Comment: I wonder, if two pieces of the matrix have some _numerical similarity_ that does not necessarily imply they are part of the same _structure_, does it? See  RotationMatrix[a] // structureForm
==> {{"a", "b"}, {-"b", "a"}}, whereas RotationMatrix[\[Pi]/4] // structureForm ==> {{"a", -"a"}, {"a", "a"}} and  RotationMatrix[\[Pi]/8] // structureForm ==> {{"a", "b"}, {-"b", "a"}}

Comment: @Sjoerd, in the examples you gave, all the matrices are [orthogonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix), so they have the same structure. Therefor, the pieces of the matrix must have some prescribed numerical similarity.

Comment: @rcollyer This is not what I meant. The current methods tend to equate numerical equality to structural equality. However, numerical equality can occur by chance without implying any structural relationship. In the above example I think the _structure_ should be {a,b} not {a,a} (with b possibly, but not necessarily equal to a).

Comment: @Sjoerd, you're correct that it could be accidental. Except in your examples, they not. The Pi/4 rotation is special in that it turns the axes into `y==x` and `y==-x`, so having `b==a` in that case is not surprising.

Comment: @rcollyer Indeed, I chose the angle specifically for the purpose of making b==a. It makes the _values_ the same but of course doesn't change anything in the _structure_ of the matrix. Anyway, nuf said about the example. My main point is still numerical equality =!= structural equality.

Comment: @Sjoerd, the more I think about it, the more I'd have to agree.  But, I think the statement is that structural equality is more strict than numerical equality, as numerical equality would miss the additional condition that the determinant of an orthogonal/unitary matrix is `PlusMinus[1]`. Then, structural equality implies some form of numerical equality, but numerical equality cannot fully imply structural equality, only hint that it may exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can start by defining the relationships that we want to recognize:

```
ClearAll@relationship
relationship[a_ -> sA_, b_ -> sB_] /; b == a := b -> sA
relationship[a_ -> sA_, b_ -> sB_] /; b == -a := b -> -sA
relationship[a_ -> sA_, b_ -> sB_] /; b == Conjugate[a] := b -> SuperStar[sA]
relationship[a_ -> sA_, b_ -> sB_] /; b == -Conjugate[a] := b -> -SuperStar[sA]
relationship[_, _] := Sequence[]
```

The form in which these relationships are expressed is convenient for the definition of `structureForm`:

```
ClearAll@structureForm
structureForm[matrix_?MatrixQ] :=
  Module[{values, rules, pairs, inferences}
  , values = matrix // Flatten // DeleteDuplicates
  ; rules = Thread[Rule[values, CharacterRange["a", "z"][[;; Length@values]]]]
  ; pairs = rules[[#]]& /@ Select[Tuples[Range[Length@values], 2], #[[1]] < #[[2]]&]
  ; inferences = relationship @@@ pairs
  ; matrix /. inferences ~Join~ rules
  ]
```

In a nutshell, this function checks each possible pair of values in the matrix inferring a substitution rule whenever a pair matches a defined relationship.  Note how the relationship definitions are expressed in terms of pairs of substitution rules in the form *value -> name*.  Matrix values are assigned letter names, proceeding from left-to-right, top-to-bottom.  Redundant inferred relationships are ignored assuming a precedence in that same order.

Beware that the function will run out of names after it finds 26 distinct values -- an alternate name-assignment strategy will be needed if that is an issue.  Also, the names are being represented as strings instead of symbols.  This conveniently dodges any unwanted bindings of the single-letter symbols names.  If symbols are preferred, it would be trivial to apply the `Symbol` function to each name.

Here are some sample uses of the function:

```
In[31]:= structureForm @ {{1, 2 + 3 I}, {2 - 3 I, 4}}

Out[31]= {{"a", "b"}, {SuperStar["b"], "d"}}

In[32]:= $m = a + b I /. a | b :> RandomInteger[{-2, 2}, {10, 10}];
         $m // MatrixForm
         $m // structureForm // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: +1, clever. I like the use of `Tuples` with `Select` to avoid go over some pairs twice. Incidentally, the use of `DeleteDuplicates` obviates the need for equality `Relationship`, but it is just a nit. What I like about the use of `Relationship` is that a set of functions could be passed in to `structureForm` taking 2 params that would become the condition on the `Relationship`. Additionally, the display could be passed in alongside the conditions. I'm going to give it a couple of days more, but this looks good.

Comment: @rcollyer The equality relationship definition is only necessary to the extent that the semantics of equality differ from `PatternMatchQ`.  Try deleting the definition and then evaluating, for example, `structureForm[{{1.0, 1}, {1.0, 1}}]`.  This may or may not be an issue in any particular application.  If the matrices can contain symbolic expressions, I was imagining that the equality relationship definition would be more elaborate, perhaps involving `Reduce`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried looking at the eigenvalues? The eigenvalues reveal a great deal of information on the structure and symmetry of matrices and are standard in statistical analysis of datasets. For e.g.,

1. Hermitian/symmetric eigenvalues have
   real eigenvalues.
2. Positive semi-definite matrices have
   non-negative eigenvalues and vice versa.
3. Rotation matrices have complex eigenvalues.
4. Circulant matrices have eigenvalues that are simply the [DFT of the first row](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix). The beauty of circulant matrices is that *every* circulant matrix has the *same* set of eigenvectors. In some cases, these results (circulant) can be extended to Toeplitz matrices.

If you're dealing with matrices that are random (an experimental observation can be modeled as a random matrix), you could also read up on [random matrix theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_matrix), which relates the distributions of eigenvalues to the underlying symmetries in the matrix and the statistical distributions of elements. Specifically,

1. The eigenvalue distribution of symmetric/hermitian Gaussian matrices is a [semicircle]
2. Eigenvalue distributions of Wishart matrices (if `A` is a random Gaussian matrix, `W=AA'` is a Wishart matrix) are given by the [Marcenko-Pastur distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marchenko%E2%80%93Pastur_distribution)

Also, the differences (spacings) between the eigenvalues also convey information about the matrix.

I'm not sure if the structure that you're looking for is like a connected graph within the matrix or something similar... I presume random matrix theory (which is more general and vast than those links will ever tell you) has some results in this regard.

Perhaps this is not really what you were looking for, but afaik, there is no one stop solution to getting the structure of a matrix. You'll have to use multiple tools to nail it down, and if I were to do it, eigenvalues would be my first pick.

Comment: @RM, you are absolutely correct in the the eigenvalues/vectors are the way to go, if the matrix is purely numerical. If the matrix is symbolic, however, the eigenvalues are less useful because of the complexity of the formulas. And, sometimes just being able to look at how the values are laid out is helpful. I realize that it can't be the only tool used, but it would be nice to have.

Comment: @rcollyer: You're right that eigenvalues are immensely helpful in numerical cases. However, I disagree that the eigenvalues are less useful in symbolic matrices. Yes, the equations become messier and as the size of your matrix grows, it'll probably get harder. But for smaller sizes, as in your examples, they're still worth a shot. The eigenvalues of a matrix are the roots of the characteristic polynomial, `|A-λI|`. Mathematica has a built in function `CharacteristicPolynomial` that will give you the expression for your matrix. Now you have a nice polynomial in terms of your variables(contd...)

Comment: and you can always use the `Discriminant`, `Δ` to set bounds on what the variables should be for it to be a particular structure... If `Δ>0`, the polynomial has real roots -> eigenvalues are real -> Hermitian/symmetric. If `Δ=0`, multiple root -> matrix is not full rank and `Δ<0`-> complex eigenvalues. These are particularly helpful if you have a symbolic matrix and you want to poke at what would happen if you were to change some of the variables. There are some more algebraic results that you can use to narrow down on the sign of the roots, which will tell you about the positive definiteness.

Comment: @RM, at least in v. 6 (I haven't tried recently), calculating the `CharacteristicPolynomial` for an 8x8 matrix would peg my CPU and take nearly 20 mins. Something about the symbolic nature of the matrix would cause it to go haywire. Personally, I'm more a fan of decomposing it according to its irreducible representations.

Comment: @RM, did not know about `Discriminant`, will have to play with it. Okay, v.7 is much better on speed, however the `CharacteristicPolynomial` isn't necessarily that revealing with that large number of terms. While it obeys the same symmetries as the matrix, the structure can easily hide in the result.

Comment: @rcollyer: I agree that `CharacteristicPolynomial` chokes up the machine even for small matrices. `Discriminant` can be quite a pain too, and will refuse to work even for "nice" polynomials. To get the discriminant out, you can use `GroebnerBasis` to eliminate the implicit polynomial and its derivative to get the discriminant. I remember a talk where the speaker reduced a matrix to the simplest tree form possible for that matrix, and then some nice combinatorics results could be easily applied (something which would not have been obvious from the matrix form). Let me see if I can find it...

Comment: @RM, any luck in finding the talk?

Comment: @rcollyer: I couldn't find the talk, but I did find [the paper](http://fr.arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/9911002), upon which the talk was based. However, on re-reading the article, I really think it is overkill for what you wanted to do in your question (I can't even begin to think how to go about doing it in mma!). So, don't get your hopes too high :)

Comment: @RM, I'll look it over, and even if it is overkill, thanks for the effort.

Comment: @RM, might be interesting for some of the many-body calcs I do, but for the most part, looks like more trouble than its worth. Thanks, though. I appreciate it.

Comment: @yoda, apparently I'm clueless, I didn't notice the name change.

Comment: @rcollyer :) had a marathon run of all 6 recently and changed in a huff... I think I'm going to stick with it though.

Comment: Recently, I've been attracted to the idea of automatically generating the symmetry operations under which a matrix remains invariant. Doing so would reveal the matrix structure via the group of symmetry ops. Generating the ops should be straight forward, the group structure, not as simple, but doable. Thoughts?